# Height List View - All rows visible

Tags: android, listview, height

I have a doubt about height in ListView. This is my case:

I have the next structure in a layout:

```
<ScrollView
...
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layouit_weight="0.8" >

   <TableLayout
   ...
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:stretchColumns="0" >

      <TableRow>
         <TextView ... />
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
         <ListView
         ...
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow> ...

   </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Each TableRow has a TextView (title) and a ListView (elements).

My problem is that my ListView always shows the first element (a row) even if it has more than one element (2 or more). You can do scroll in ListView and you see that ListView has all elements, but in the screen the ListView has a reduced height, it only shows a row.

I have put '**wrap_content**' in ListView's height, but I don't know why it hasn't the enough height to show all elements.

However, if I put a fixed value in ListView's height (e.g. 200 dp) it takes that value, is higher, and I can see all items at the same time. Why?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: scroll view with listview, don't you think its a poor UI design? and secondly Place your whole code than its easy to understand your words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add height for each row at runtime.

Comment: How? I want that ListView has height as wrap_content, that is, as high as elements it has.

Comment: First you have to find total height of list view by getting height of each row element of row and multiplying row height with the total number of items in list view. Then you have to set this total height to list view using:
listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, totalHeight));

or

Instead of using listview you can use linearlayout and add items by inflating row views by using addChild() method.

Comment: Good response @Arun Kumar ! I have put 'listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, totalHeight));' and it works!! I have to use a ListView because I use a BaseAdapter for controlling some elements therefore LinearLayout is discarded. However, I don't understand why wrap_content doesn't work ... in other ListViews in my app works well! Maybe, due to it is within ScrollView

Comment: Now, the problem is that devices with different density value for the height of each row changes ... =$